# How to get JSON response and parse through it

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to get a JSON response from an API, the issue I am having is that I am trying to parse through the JSON, and I keep getting this error

`Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'`

This is after I am getting my response using Alamofire:

```swift
        AF.request("http://localhost:8080/todos").responseJSON { response in
            print(response.description["username"])
        }
```

But when I try to parse using:

`print(response.description["username"])`

That is when I end up getting the error, I was wondering if I am doing something wrong, or am I missing a step

Comment: `description` is a property of type `String`. That's not how you access the results from the response.

Comment: When reviewing the answers in the duplicate, please be sure to look at answers that use Swift 3 or later and proper Swift collections.

Comment: can you share your.json file